# ng-click not working on table row in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is a follow up to this question: [How do I get my model to my Directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412688/how-do-i-get-my-model-to-my-directive)

The directive is displaying the data, but the ng-click does nothing.

my partial page looks like this now:

```
<div>selected user:{{selectedUser.UserName}} </div>

<div user-list data-users="users"></div>
```

and my directive now looks like this:

```
tsUui.directive('userList', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<table>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<th>User Name</th>'+
                        '<th>First Name</th>'+
                        '<th>Last Name</th>'+
                        '<th>Email Address</th>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                    '<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="selectUser(user)">'+
                        '<td>{{user.UserName}}</td>'+
                        '<td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>'+
                        '<td>{{user.LastName}}</td>'+
                        '<td>{{user.Email}}</td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                '</table>',
        scope:{
                selectedUser: '=',
                users: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs){
            scope.selectUser = function(user){
                console.log("hi");
                selectedUser=user;
            };
        }
    }
});
```

the data is displaying properly, but when I click on a row nothing happens: no console logs, the selected user doesn't change...nothing.  What am i doing wrong?

Edit: the console is logging it, but the selected user binding doesn't change...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to do it like this:

```
scope.selectedUser=user;
```

also I changed the partial to this:

```
<div>selected user:{{selection.UserName}} </div>

<div user-list data-users="users" selected-user="selection"></div>
```